# ActiveReports Chart WallXY Shading

Tags: charts, activereports

I'm working on a chart in ActiveReports 8 and I'm having problems setting the background color for the chart. I've found that I can change the color with chart.ChartAreas(0).WallXY.Backdrop.Color =  but it always appears to be shaded. For example, when I set it to White the background color appears to be light gray. Is there a way to control how/if ActiveReports shades the walls on a chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that setting

```
chart.ChartAreas(0).Light.Type = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Chart.LightType.Ambient
```

removes the shading from all of the walls in the chart. This allowed me to set the colors how I wanted them without ActiveReports affecting the colors/shading.